# Getting Minimum Grid Area Altitude from navigational chart

Tags: navigation, aeronautical-charts

One of the questions for the EASA PPL(A) exam sounds like this:

> What is the highest Minimum Grid Area Altitude between BERTA (point 1) and LJLJ (Ljubljana) along route A (yellow)?

And the following chart is provided:

[image]

The correct answer is 10700 ft, but I'm not sure why and how to detect this from this chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Minimum Grid Area Altitude in each sector is depicted by the truncated numbers shown in the circle below.  (*There are several sectors shown in your photo, and the sector further west showing **97** is 9,700' for comparison.  You can see a couple others at the very top of the image as well.*)

[image]